# Jira/ALM Structure - Gantt dates not accessible in formulas

Tags: structure, jira

I am using ALM structure and I am trying to write a formula that uses the Gantt finish date that structure calculates.  When I add it to the formula I cannot assign it to a variable since I cannot find it in the Source list.  The Gantt finish date is the date that is calculated by structure as the start date plus the duration.  It moves as the duration and start date change.

[image: Structure]

I have tried searching for the Gantt date by looking for finish date, end date, etc, but it cannot find any variable that directly associates with this date.

Comment: [Documentation](https://wiki.almworks.com/documentation/gantt/3.5/data-center-and-server/gantt-attributes-in-structure-146079785.html#id-.GanttAttributesinStructurev3.3-UsingGanttAttributesinFormulas) said it is possible.